# Next.js not routing to pages in the same subfolder

Tags: routes, next.js

I currently have my next.js pages folder setup with the following structure.

```
/pages
  /apps
    /items
      index.js
      view.js
      create.js
```

From index.js (apps/items) I am trying to link to the view page (apps/item/view) using the Link component and the links do not work. If a try and open them in a new tab or use regular  tags it works but using the next/link component nothing happens.

I have tried using the routeChangeStart Router event to see if the link fires and it does but never get a routeChangeEnd does not fire.

I have my link components set like so.

```
          <Link
            href={{
              pathname: "/apps/items/view",
              query: { id: id }
            }}
          >
            <a>Item ID: {id}</a>
          </Link>
```

I get no error messages in the console or on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a problem with importing CSS in your components. Looks like its a known issue. For more information see here. 
https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/282